# Magic Line in navigation menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Im trying to put a "Magic Line" in the menu of my website: http://bioda.bg/

I`ve been following this guide: https://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

At first it worked (and sometimes it works as it should), but most of the time it is more on the right than it should and has more width than it should. Can someone explain to me why does that happens? And how can I "debug" it to get to that conclusion myself?

Ive hardcoded the width of the nav, but Im not sure if that is the problem.

This is my JS:

```
(function($) {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#top-menu");

$mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");


$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());


$("#top-menu li a").hover(function() {
    $el = $("#top-menu li a:hover");
    leftPos = $el.parent().position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
})(jQuery);
```

At first it was working normally, but then after 1-2 days it just started to not working as it should. At first I thought its from my custom extension to the code, but I removed it and its the same again.

I was trying to use this code:

```
if($(".current_page_item").length != 0) {
    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
} else {
    $magicLine
        .width(114)
        .css("left", 85)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
}
```

I tried to use this so when there is no current_page_item class in any of the menu items, Im hardcoding the position and width it should get (which always will be for the 2nd menu item). But anyway I removed that, and still doesnt work.

Would be very greatful if someone explains the whole situation, because Im lost. Tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: It appears to work whenever the page is cached, so it looks like it's a timing issue. To verify you can try a setTimout() for the init. I am not sure what other scripts are running on the page, but I would try commenting them out one by one. Another possibility is that an image is causing a problem, but that is less likely as the #top-menu has a set width.

Comment: Could you explain where exacly do you mean to do the setTimeout()? And I was wondering, now that Im done with the website, to install any caching plugin. I guess this will also help.

Comment: Check out this link: [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more information. But basically you can put delay your code from fireing for ~10 milliseconds to ensure that fires after anything else that might be causing it to at a bad time.